# Pivot data in a single LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This should be easy. I want to get some properties of the data but it is not in a form that makes it easy for me to get in a single statement. How would I change this into a single XML to LINQ statement ? Here is how I do it now

```
   XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(result.Result.ToString());

        string id = (from c in xdoc.Descendants("Fields").Elements("Field")
                 where (string)c.Attribute("FieldId") == "1"
                 select new
                 {
                     Id = c.Attribute("Value").Value
                 }).First().Id;

        string firstName = (from c in xdoc.Descendants("Fields").Elements("Field")
                     where (string)c.Attribute("FieldId") == "2"
                     select new
                     {
                         firstName = c.Attribute("Value").Value
                     }).First().firstName;


        <Fields>
          <Field FieldId = "1" Value="1908551075" FieldTitle="Ref Id" FieldType="Text" />
          <Field FieldId = "2" Value="Mary" FieldTitle="First Name" FieldType="Text" />
          <Field FieldId = "3" Value="Crippen" FieldTitle="Last Name" FieldType="Text" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
             "<Root>" +
             "<Fields>" +
              "<Field FieldId = \"1\" Value=\"1908551075\" FieldTitle=\"Ref Id\" FieldType=\"Text\" />" +
              "<Field FieldId = \"2\" Value=\"Mary\" FieldTitle=\"First Name\" FieldType=\"Text\" />" +
              "<Field FieldId = \"3\" Value=\"Crippen\" FieldTitle=\"Last Name\" FieldType=\"Text\" />" +
              "</Fields>" +
              "</Root>";

            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            var results = xDoc.Descendants("Fields").Select(x => new {
                ID = x.Descendants("Field").Where(y => y.Attribute("FieldTitle").Value == "Ref Id").Select(z => z.Attribute("Value").Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                firstName = x.Descendants("Field").Where(y => y.Attribute("FieldTitle").Value == "First Name").Select(z => z.Attribute("Value").Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                lastName = x.Descendants("Field").Where(y => y.Attribute("FieldTitle").Value == "Last Name").Select(z => z.Attribute("Value").Value).FirstOrDefault(),
            }).ToList();


        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 4):

I would convert it to Dictionary

```
var dict = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring)
            .Descendants("Field")
            .ToDictionary(f => f.Attribute("FieldTitle").Value, 
                          f => f.Attribute("Value").Value);

Console.WriteLine(dict["Ref Id"] + " " +  dict["Last Name"]);
```

**EDIT**

For multiple *fields*

```
var fields  = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring)
             .Descendants("Fields")
             .Select(flds => flds.Descendants("Field")
                             .ToDictionary(f => f.Attribute("FieldTitle").Value, 
                                           f => f.Attribute("Value").Value))
             .ToList();

foreach (var field in fields)
{
    Console.WriteLine(field["Ref Id"] + " " + field["Last Name"]);
}
```

Comment: this may work when you have only one "Fields", but doesn't work well with multiple "Fields".

Comment: @jdweng If this is the case, be sure I can fix my answer easily.

Comment: There are about 70 fields

Comment: @punkouter If that is the case why didn't you post an xml representing your case. I think you have enough experience on SO to know how to ask a good question.

Comment: I think the dictionary will be good when I am not hardcoding the properties. So I appreciate both answers. I may switch to it at some point